# select tag send null value when submit using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am using the following code to fill select tag from database using asp.net and c#.
it works fine and display data correctly, but when i am submitting the form to another page   i got null value for selected data
here is my code in Collages.aspx page

```
<select class="form-control" id="uni_name" name="uni_name" runat="server">

</select>
```

and this is code of Collages.aspx.cs that fill select tag

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new DB_Connection().getConnection();
    SqlDataAdapter uni_adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select uni_id,uni_name from universities", conn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    uni_adapter.Fill(ds);

    uni_name.DataSource = ds;
    uni_name.DataTextField = "uni_name";
    uni_name.DataValueField = "uni_id";
    uni_name.DataBind();
}
```

and here is the code i use to get selected value

```
 Response.Write(Request.Form["uni_name"]);
```

could you please  help in this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please write your code inside isPostback

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new DB_Connection().getConnection();
    SqlDataAdapter uni_adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select uni_id,uni_name from universities", conn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    uni_adapter.Fill(ds);

    uni_name.DataSource = ds;
    uni_name.DataTextField = "uni_name";
    uni_name.DataValueField = "uni_id";
    uni_name.DataBind();
}
}
```

Comment: no working.
the problem isn't with displaying data the problem when i submit the form it send null value for this select tag

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the order of events in the ASP.NET page creation process. The post back data is processed between the `OnInit` and `OnLoad` events. As you do not fill your select until the `OnLoad` event, it does exist when the viewdata in the postback is being processed.

Move your code from `Page_Load` into `Page_Intit` and the select with its data will exist when the viewdata is processed.

Comment: doesn't work i put the code inside onInit but the same. my problem isn't with displaying data inside the select tag the problem is after click submit button it sends null value